# Decide which category to drop in pandas get_dummies()

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

Let's say I have the following df:

```
data = [{'c1':a, 'c2':x}, {'c1':b,'c2':y}, {'c1':c,'c2':z}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Output:

       c1 c2
    0  a  x
    1  b  y
    2  c  z
```

Now I want to use pd.get_dummies() to one hot encode the two categorical columns c1 and c2 and drop the first category of each col `pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['c1', 'c2'], drop_first=True)`. How can I decide which category to drop, without knowing the rows' order? Is there any command I missed?

---

**EDIT:**
So my goal would be to e.g., drop category `b` from `c1` and `z` from `c2`

```
Output:

       a  c  x  y
    0  1  0  1  0
    1  0  0  0  1
    2  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: So need remove e.g. for first column second category, for second colum first? Not sure if understand.

Comment: Yeah. I too have difficulty in understanding your definition of what is first! @TiTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick is replace values to `NaN`s - here is removed one value per rows:

```
#columns with values for avoid
d = {'c1':'b', 'c2':'z'}

d1 = {k:{v: np.nan} for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.get_dummies(df.replace(d1), columns = ['c1', 'c2'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
print (df)
   a  c  x  y
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0
```

If need multiple values for remove per column use lists like:

```
d = {'c1':['b','c'], 'c2':['z']}

d1 = {k:{x: np.nan for x in v} for k, v in d.items()}
print (d1)
{'c1': {'b': nan, 'c': nan}, 'c2': {'z': nan}}

df = pd.get_dummies(df.replace(d1), columns = ['c1', 'c2'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
print (df)
   a  x  y
0  1  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  0  0
```

EDIT:

If values are unique per columns simplier is them removed in last step:

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['c1', 'c2'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
        .drop(['b','z'], axis=1))
print (df)
   a  c  x  y
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using `sklearn` instead! https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

You can view the categories accessing the `<your_fitted_instance_name>.categories_` attribute after you've fitted the one hot encoder, and it also has a `inverse_transform()` function to reverse the one hot encoding!

As for column dropping.. the default is not to drop any. However, you can use `OneHotEncoder(drop='first')` in order to drop one.

**Edit**: Also note that `sklearn` offers Pipelines which can help you ensure consistent pre-processing throughout your project!
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
pd.get_dummies(, drop_first = False)
```

Then manually drop the level you don't want:

```
df.drop('dum_b_z', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).